# Finding the number of nonnegative integer solutions of $z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_4 = 10$ satisfying given restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find the number of solutions of $$z_1 + z_2 + z_3 +z_4=10$$ where $z_i$ are nonnegative integers such that $z_1\le 4,z_2$ is odd,$z_3$ is prime and $z_4\in\{1,2,3,6,8\}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: In particular, please edit the question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I do not know even how to start :(

Comment: Do you know how to solve the problem without restrictions?

Comment: First simplify the problem by showing for z4 = 6, 8 there is only one solution.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig If it were without restrictions,I know that the answer would be 13 choose 10

Answer (score 3):

The restricions are so haphazard that there is nothing else but going through the cases. I let Mathematica do it for me:

[image]

The answer then is $24$.

Comment: Thank you.Is there another way to do it without computer ?